# Perforce Reconcile Offline Work filter is too long

Tags: perforce

As the attached image demonstrates, I'm filtering a significant amount of files that VS generates automatically, and this causes Perforce's Reconcile Offline Work window to become large & unwieldy, since it expands in order to display a string representation of the filter without line wrapping.

Is there any way to remove this string representation, make sure it'll wrap or solve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using a bunch of exclusions, could you use a P4IGNORE file instead (even temporarily)?

The documentation is [here](http://www.perforce.com/blog/120214/new-20121-p4ignore) and [this blog post](http://www.perforce.com/blog/120214/new-20121-p4ignore) has some details on its usage.